# How can I position my image to be in the centre while combining PHP and HTML elements using bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**QUESTION**

How can I add this [icon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4trHjl5zgAhWo1eAKHdGBCVEQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpixabay.com%2Fen%2Fwww-icon-website-world-web-upload-1632431%2F&psig=AOvVaw0uApgQYSMxDYW5hkdSITaD&ust=1549167222640075) above my browser name and version in my program using bootstrap version 4? In order for the layout to be fully responsive.

I know from doing research the below code will enable me to centre the icon I want. However, the part where I'm getting confused is how to place it above the browser name and version.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/31/00/44/www-1632431_1280.png" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:15%"> 
</div>
```

**MODIFIED CODE**

```
    <?php
   function getBrowser()
   {
       $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       $bname = 'Unknown';
       $platform = 'Unknown';
       $version= "";

       //First get the platform?
       if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
           $platform = 'linux';
       }
       elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
           $platform = 'mac';
       }
       elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
           $platform = 'windows';
       }

       // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
       if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
           $ub = "MSIE";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
           $ub = "Firefox";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Google Chrome';
           $ub = "Chrome";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Apple Safari';
           $ub = "Safari";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Opera';
           $ub = "Opera";
       }
       elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
       {
           $bname = 'Netscape';
           $ub = "Netscape";
       }

       // finally get the correct version number
       $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
       $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
       ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
       if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
           // we have no matching number just continue
       }

       // see how many we have
       $i = count($matches['browser']);
       if ($i != 1) {
           //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
           //see if version is before or after the name
           if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
               $version= $matches['version'][0];
           }
           else {
               $version= $matches['version'][1];
           }
       }
       else {
           $version= $matches['version'][0];
       }

       // check if we have a number
       if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

       return array(
           'userAgent' => $u_agent,
           'name'      => $bname,
           'version'   => $version,
           'platform'  => $platform,
           'pattern'    => $pattern
       );
   }

   $ua=getBrowser();
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: lightblue;
         }
         html, body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         display: table
         }
         #content {
         display: table-cell;
         text-align: center;
         vertical-align: middle
         }
         .text {
         font-weight: bold;
         text-decoration: underline;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_542923.png" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:15%"> 
      </div>
      <?php
      $ua=getBrowser();
      $yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'];
      $version= "Version of the browser  you're using is : " . $ua['version'];
      echo "<div class='text animated bounceInRight' id='content' style='text-align: center;'>".$yourbrowser."<br/>".$version."</div>";
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting the php code inside the <body> ?

Comment: I have to use php in my assignment. However, I'm wondering instead of using `echo` to style and output the browser information and version, I was wondering if it's possible to bring them variables over to my HTML and then I could simply use bootstrap and then output the PHP output variables under my image.

Comment: Liam, You are on the right track.

Comment: Serve the style variables with a PHP API. Inserting PHP code inside the production html is a **very bad practice**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_542923.png" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:15%">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                    <?php
                       $ua=getBrowser();
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 text animated bounceInRight" id="content">
                       <?php echo "Your browser: {$ua['name']}"; ?>
                       <br />
                       <?php echo "Version of the browser you're using is : {$ua['version']}"; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/93mopd4h/ Am I placing the code correctly within my code? It seems to be formatted in a strange way . https://imgur.com/a/S36hhL5

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/365145181067f5bc013735aba39cd59dd8408f5f

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be a problem? You can do it like that

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: lightblue;
         }
         html, body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         display: table
         }
         .container {
         display: table-cell;
         text-align: center;
         vertical-align: middle
         }
         .text {
         font-weight: bold;
         text-decoration: underline;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/31/00/44/www-1632431_1280.png" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:15%">
          <?php
          $ua=getBrowser();
          $yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'];
          $version= "Version of the browser  you're using is : " . $ua['version'];
          echo "<div class='text animated bounceInRight' id='content' style='text-align: center;'>".$yourbrowser."<br/>".$version."</div>";
          ?>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I modified my current in the OG post. I can't seem to get the variables and image to be in the middle horizontally and vertically.